# How to extract multiple new columns from a complex string in R (str_sub does not seem to do the trick)

Tags: r, string, extract, gsub

I am struggling with extracting multiple variables from a string in R.

The column looks like this:

`7 digit identifier`_`NAME`:`4 digit value`-`4 digit value`-`4 digit value`-`location1`-`location2`:`7-digit identifier`_`junk`_`junk`_`3 digit value with junk attached`

so for example:

```
1234567_NAME:0011-1234-0176-town-car:1234567_000001_original_010qyz
```

I need new columns with:

- the 7 digit identifier ("1234567")
- the NAME
- each of the of 4 digit values
- each location
- the 3 digit value

`str_sub()` doesn't work since the length of some parts of the string is variable.

I tried `gsub`, but since some special characters are repeated multiple times (i.e. the ":' and "-") I can't use them to extract a well-defined part of the string.

Comment: Look into regex. It's designed for this kind of thing. The package `stringr` has a useful method called `str_extract` that lets you take regex matches out of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid lengthy regular expression, one option is to split the columns into a matrix using `str_split_fixed` with `[_:-]` as delimiter, remove columns you don't need and extract numeric values from the last column:

```
s <- "1234567_NAME:0011-1234-0176-town-car:1234567_000001_original_010qyz"
ss <- c(s,s,s)

library(stringr)
mat <- str_split_fixed(ss, "[_:-]", 11)[,-c(9, 10)]
mat
#     [,1]      [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]  [,8]      [,9]    
#[1,] "1234567" "NAME" "0011" "1234" "0176" "town" "car" "1234567" "010qyz"
#[2,] "1234567" "NAME" "0011" "1234" "0176" "town" "car" "1234567" "010qyz"
#[3,] "1234567" "NAME" "0011" "1234" "0176" "town" "car" "1234567" "010qyz"

mat[,9] <- sub("(\\d{3}).*", "\\1", mat[,9])
mat
#     [,1]      [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]  [,8]      [,9] 
#[1,] "1234567" "NAME" "0011" "1234" "0176" "town" "car" "1234567" "010"
#[2,] "1234567" "NAME" "0011" "1234" "0176" "town" "car" "1234567" "010"
#[3,] "1234567" "NAME" "0011" "1234" "0176" "town" "car" "1234567" "010"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the "lengthy" regex, then you can do something like this (and add record validation later on since you've embedded the field lengths):

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

pat <- "(.{7})_([[:alnum:][:space:]]+):([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:alnum:][:space:]]+)-([[:alnum:][:space:]]+):([[:digit:]]{7})_[[:alnum:][:space:]]+_[[:alnum:][:space:]]+_([[:digit:]]{3})"

dat <- "1234567_NAME:0011-1234-0176-town-car:1234567_000001_original_010qyz"
dat <- rep(dat, 10)

cols <- c("id", "name", "val1", "val2", "val3", "loc1", "loc2", "val3")

stri_match_all_regex(dat, pat) %>% 
  map_df(~setNames(as.list(.[,c(2:8,10)]), cols))
## # A tibble: 10 x 7
##         id  name  val1  val2  val3  loc1  loc2
##      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
## 1  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 2  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 3  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 4  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 5  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 6  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 7  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 8  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 9  1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
## 10 1234567  NAME  0011  1234   010  town   car
```

Comment: Wow, thank you both so much for the detailed and quick feedback Psidom and hrbrmstr! I tried both suggestions and they both work perfectly (and pretty fast, the dataset contains >2.000.000 rows). I cant upvote because of my newbie status, but I seriously appreciate your time!